# Reporting Services report logs report destination

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have SSRS 2008 and have a heap of data driven subscriptions.
We've been tasked with creating a map of all the reports every user receives.

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog2
```

gives us almost the information we want.
For what we want, it lacks the destination of the report.

Is there a way of finding out where a report was emailed?

My alternative I guess is to look at analysing the Exchange logs.
Is that a reasonable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the destination of the data driven subscription from columns Parameters and DataSettings in the table Subscription from report server database.
The 2 columns record as xml format , you could get the  node in column Parameters and get the  node in column DataSettings. Then you could get correspond receiver for subscription.